# Good alternative to Ghostery for mobile browsers Chrome (android) and Safari (ios)

Tags: mobile-safari, event-tracking, mobile-browser, mobile-chrome

I need to use Ghostery because I need to hide my information from tracking. It's ok for desktop browsers but Ghostery doesn't have extension for mobile browsers. They only has separate browser for mobile devices. I tried to find antitracking extension but had fail - another (Privacy Budget, uMatrix) has only separate browser or fit only for desktop browsers. 
Could tou tell me, please, what antitracking tools for mobile browsers (Chrome and Safary) do you use?